# Mysql query using 3 table returns wrong data

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

Table 1 -> Access Control

```
1) user_uuid
2) product_id
3) facebook_uuid
```

Table 2 -> Product table

```
1) product_id
2) product_name
3) status
4) visibility
5) result
6) user_uuid
```

Table 3 -> Bidding table

```
1) product_id
2) user_uuid
3) options
```

Sample data

Product table :-

```
ID - Name - status - visibility - result  - user_uuid
1  - T1   - 1      -     1      -   0     -    1
2  - T2   - 1      -     1      -   0     -    1
3  - T3   - 0      -     0      -   1     -    1
```

Access Control

```
user_uuid    -    product_id    -    facebook_uuid

    1        -        1         -         123
    1        -        1         -         456
    1        -        1         -         789

    1        -        2         -         123
    1        -        2         -         456
    1        -        2         -         789

    1        -        3         -         123
    1        -        3         -         456
    1        -        3         -         789
```

Bidding Table :- Initially this table won't have any data as once any user bid on product then only this data will be entered.

```
product_id   -   user_uuid   - options
   1         -      2        -  123.35
```

User table :-

```
user_uuid   -   facebook_uuid
   1        -      007
   2        -      123
   3        -      456
   4        -      789
```

Explanation :-

User 1 created 3 product and share other facebook users. For managing sharing we have create access control table where we track the records of product shared with other users by user 1. You can check that in access control table.

Now products are shared with others so users will be able to see the products on their screen as its shared with them.

We have 2 tabs on screen -> Shared & Bid.

Shared -> Here users will see the products which is shared with them but they have not bid on the product yet. Once user bid on any product we make entry in bid table which is shown above.

Bid -> Here users will see the products which they have bid.

Our query :-

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT TABLE 
WHERE product_id IN 
    ( SELECT product_id 
      from ACCESS TABLE 
      where facebook_uuid ='123' 
        and product_id not in 
           ( Select product_id from BID TABLE) 
    )  
or product_id IN 
    ( SELECT product_id 
      from ACCESS TABLE 
      where user_uuid  IN 
           ( select user_uuid 
             from USER TABLE 
             where facebook_uuid = '123' 
           ) 
       and product_id not in 
           ( Select product_id from BID TABLE )
     ) 
AND result = 0 
AND status = 1 
AND visibility = 1
```

This should return me PRODUCT 2 as USER 2 has already placed BID for product 1 AND PRODUCT 3 status & visibility criteria is not matching. BUT above query is giving me PRODUCT 2 & 3 both which wrong.

We are using 3 table for getting data and looking for help of expert to guide.

NOTE - WE HAVE TO CHECK 2 THINGS IMPORTANTLY WHICH WE ARE UNABLE TO DO IN OUR QUERY IS THAT, USER MUST NOT HAVE BID AND SHARED WITH USER BY THE PRODUCT CREATOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First subquery selects products what shared with given user, and second subquery selects products what given user already bid on. So query selects product what are `in` first list (selected by first subquery) but `not in` second list (selected by second subquery).

```
select *
from product_table
where
    result=0 and
    status=1 and
    visibility=1 and
    product_id in (
        select product_id            
        from access_table
        where facebook_uuid='123'
    ) and
    product_id not in (
        select product_id
        from
            bid_table join
            user_table on user_table.user_uuid=bid_table.user_uuid
        where facebook_uuid='123'
    )
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59cb/2

Comment: Thank you for your input but its not working. Returning empty as result.

Comment: @Scorpion I test my query on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59cb/1/0) with your test data and it return product 2 as you wanted.